# Vietnamese input method

Tags: ibus

After re-installing Ubuntu 13.10, the Vietnamese input settings in iBus changed. Before this it used the telex input method (same as Android and iOS defaults). Now it has a very strange keyboard with the diacritic accents replacing the number row. I would like to use the standard telex method if possible because the new layout is very bizarre and also makes it impossible to type numbers without switching back to English temporarily unless one has a numeric keypad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to install `ibus-unikey:`

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-unikey
ibus-daemon -Rd
im-config
```

When reconfiguring `im-config` you choose *IBus* as the default input method.

Require to have language Vietnamese installed - a good guide as detail [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/945308/22308) to do so

After that open *System* → *IBus preferences* and add *Unikey* to input methods.

[image]

[image]

Finally, add *Vietnamese* keyboard in *System* → *Region & Language* and then you have telex your own.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works for me with this [guide](http://nguyenhuuhoang.com/huong-dan-cai-bo-go-tieng-viet-tren-ubuntu-16-04-lts-ibus-unikey/).

Steps:

- Install & restart `ibus unikey`:

  ```
  sudo apt install -y ibus-unikey 
  ibus restart
  ```
- Then, go to *Start menu* → *Text entry settings* → add *Vietnamese (ibus)*.