# What can I do to make ibus-unikey work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ibus

I use an Asus GL552VW and I installed Ubuntu 16.04. I searched Google "How to type Vietnamese on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS" but after I installed `ibus-unikey` (for typing Vietnamese), it wasn't working. I found all solutions on the internet but still it's not working.

After I installed Ubuntu 16.04, I did this:

- chose best server.
- used `sudo apt-get update` for updates and `sudo apt-get upgrade` for upgrade
- used `sudo apt-get install ibus-unikey` to install `ibus-unikey`
- restarted ibus by `ibus restart`
- went to Text Entry and added "Vietnamese (Unikey) (iBus)"
- went to `im-config` to choose iBus
- went to `ibus-setup` to add Vietnamese -> Unikey
- in Language and region, clicked "Install language" -> Vietnamese -> Apply
- logged out then logged in

But still not working.

Can anybody tell me what I can do to make `ibus-unikey` work? In Ubuntu 14.04, `ibus-unikey` worked fine on my laptop. Thanks.

Comment: I follow your steps to install ibus and setting on Ubuntu Desktop 17 and succeeded.

Comment: You may need to install `ibus-unikey` https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/ibus-unikey/

Answer (score 2):

I just got it working. Note that I DIDN'T have to go into Language and Region to make any changes on Mint MATE 18 but not sure about Ubuntu.

After doing `ibus-unikey install` and `ibus-setup` as you did, I went into `im-config` and selected 'OK' to the screen asking,

> Do you explicitly select the user configuration?

I clicked 'yes' and then chose ibus. After a reboot it worked.

chúc may mắn

Answer (score 1):

We have to enable ibus-unikey after installed it.

> #### Step 1:
>
> - Open **System Settings**/**Language Support**
> - In **Language** tab/**keyboard input method system** choose ***Ibus***
> - Install Vietnamese if you did not.
>
> #### Step 2:
>
> - Log out and log in (or reboot)
>
> #### Step 3:
>
> - Open **System Settings**/**Text Entry**
> - Hit '**+**' to add the "***Vietnamese(Unikey)(IBus)***"
> - ( Make sure the "*Show current input source in the menu bar*" was ticked )

After log out and log in (or reboot), you'll see the Unikey option.
Hope this help you and the others !!

Chúc bạn thành công.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mike,

I got it working by following Mike's steps above, with a minor change here and there, perhaps due to different version of Ubuntu.

The steps to enable Viet keyboard on my device with Ubuntu 17.10 are as follows:

```
Step 1:

    Open System Settings/Language Support.
    In Language tab, hit 'Install / Remove Languages'.
    Scroll down the list and tick box 'Vietnamese' and Apply.


Step 2:

    Reboot.


Step 3:

    Open Settings/Region & Language.
    Hit '+' button to add "Vietnamese (Unikey)".
    Reboot.
```

I was then be able to view (en/viet) and choose different keyboard at the top right hand corner of the screen.

Chúc các bạn may mắn.

cheers - ac