# Vietnamese keyboard layout with xfce on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: keyboard-layout, xfce, 19.10

We use different languages for keyboard input including the US keyboard with Vietnamese characters from the settings/keyboard/layout panel in Ubuntu-Studio 19.10 (xfce).

Using the Vietnamese keyboard variant seems to be our main issue, as: where are the Vietnamese characters? How does one produce the required accented characters? How to use the "Compose" key, or rather, what are the  required character sequences to get the Vietnamese accented characters.

A visual display showing this would be nice, but xkeycaps does not seem to know about Vietnamese characters.

The physical keyboard is PC 105 keys.

Where could we find the relevant information?

Thank you,

ac

Comment: This might be of help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/851526/what-can-i-do-to-make-ibus-unikey-work-on-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1

Comment: Yes, but the issue is not so much about configuration, but on the documentation of the layout, characters, and keys to use to get the different Vietnamese characters. We configured everything proposed in your reference. We do not see "Vietnamese (unikey)" as an option, but we have "Vietnamese (us with Vietnamese letters)" and "Vietnamese (French with Vietnamese letters)" as available options. What key sequences are required to generate characters as " ự " or " ṓ "? A Vietnamese keyboard layout map and/or character sequence list, should be fine.