# How to type numbers in Vietnamese standard input method (not Bamboo, not UniKey)?

Tags: kde, keyboard-layout, input-method

I am wondering if anyone here knows how to use bizarre keyboard layout that comes together with standard input methods on Ubuntu-based systems. When I type:
`1234567890-=\ I get:` ăâêộ̀̉̃́đ-₫
and it's ok, but how you actually type numbers when you need?
Alt+Ă, Shift+Ă, Alt+Shift+Ă doesn't work. Probably it is linked to default shortcuts on KDE and it needs to be disabled first, but which one?

Please, don't get me wrong, I really know about Bamboo, UniKey, etc. and how to use them. The question is about using default input methods (as per year 2022) and not about alternatives.

Update:
Image of the Layout Preview in KDE System Settings

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, `AltGr + 12345...` on that input method and look at `System Settings > Region & Language` Add Laten keyboard which you like, this is my best guess. https://askubuntu.com/questions/428673/vietnamese-input-method

Comment: Added picture of the bizarre layout that I am trying to learn.